# Using sed to convert newlines into spaces

Tags: shell, sed

Say I have a shell variable `$string` that holds some text with several newlines, e.g.:

```
string="this
is 
a test"
```

I would like to convert this string into a new string `new_string` where all line breaks are converted into spaces:

```
new_string="this is a test"
```

I tried:

```
print $string | sed 's/\n/ /g'
```

but it didn't work

I'm also wondering if there is a way of doing this using  `perl -0777 's/\n/ /g'` or maybe the command `tr` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n

Comment: In my case, I needed some alternative to matching multi-line strings with `grep --null-data` where the `--null-data` option wasn’t available. Some form of `echo $string | grep …` was good enough for me.

Comment: For Bash, see: [Stack Overflow: Replace `\n` (new line) with space in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39198780/4561887)

Answer (score 95, accepted):

If you only want to remove the new lines in the string, you don't need to use `sed`. You can use just

```
$  echo "$string" | tr '\n' ' '
```

as others had pointed.

But if you want to convert new lines into spaces on a file using `sed`, then you can use:

```
# for a file
$ sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' file_with_line_breaks

# for a string
$ new_string="$(echo "$string" | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g')"
```

or even `awk`:

```
$ awk '$1=$1' ORS=' ' file_with_line_breaks > new_file_with_spaces
```

Comment: `sponge` is a useful utility for overwriting an input file. It is part of package `moreutils` ... eg.  `awk '$1=$1' ORS=' ' file |sponge file`

Comment: @ferer Thanks for the information. Installing `moreutils`...

Comment: Your first command will add a space at the end. Also it may fail if the `$string` starts with a dash `-`. To avoid both the problems you should use `printf`: `printf %s "$string" | tr '\n' ' '`

Answer (score 12):

Yet another option would be to use `xargs` (which, in addition, squeezes multiple white space):

```
string="this
    is 
a    test"

printf "$string" | xargs   # this is a test
```

Comment: Do not use the string as the formatting argument of `printf`. This will fail if it contains the formatting characters like `%` or ``\``. Do this instead: `printf %s "$string"`

Answer (score 10):

If you already have the string as a bash variable, as your example shows, it is pointless and wasteful of resources (and more typing) to call `sed`, `awk`, `printf`, etc... You can just use *bash variable expansion*:

```
string="${string//$'\n'/ }"
```

You don't even have to re-assign it. You can use the expansion as-is, and leave `$string` unchanged.

```
printf "${string//$'\n'/ }" >file
```

Answer (score 9):

You could try using `tr` instead:

```
echo "$string" | tr '\n' ' '
```

Answer (score 5):

You could try this awk command also,

```
awk -v RS="" '{gsub (/\n/," ")}1' file
```

**Example:**

```
$ (echo This; echo is; echo a; echo test.) | awk -v RS="" '{gsub (/\n/," ")}1'
This is a test.
```

Answer (score 3):

Echo ignores white space, so it should work:

```
new_string=`echo $string`
```

Comment: Yes, it will work, **but** perhaps too well. It will collapse multi whitespace to a single space. That includes converting TABs to spaces.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the simple sed command

```
 $-sed ':loop;N;s/\n/ /g;t loop'
```

Comment: With in-place editing: `sed -i ':loop;N;s/\n/ /g;t loop' file.txt`

Answer (score 1):

```
state=$(set +o)
set -f ; IFS='
'; set -- $string
unset IFS; string="$*"
eval "$state"
```

This converts any sequence of one or more `\n`ewline characters occurring in the shell variable `$string`into a single `<space>`.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is old, but you don't to use `sed` for this. If you really need to use `sed`, just look at the above answers.

Like @user57553's answer, you could use `xargs`. I personally would do `xargs echo` for more POSIX compliance (if it even is).

You can just do:

```bsh
COMMAND | xargs echo
```

where `COMMAND` is well, the command.

If it's a file, do:

```bsh
xargs echo < FILE
```

where `FILE` is the file you are trying to convert.

To do it backwards (spaces to newlines), do:

```bsh
COMMAND | tr " " "\n"
```

If it's a file, do:

```bsh
tr " " "\n" < FILE
```

where `FILE` is the file you are trying to convert.